# Unanswered questions reminder

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Just a reminder to everyone.

Sometimes questions get forgotten about or slip past our view on a day to day basis.

There are currently 41 unanswered questions I've flagged the ones I deemed are next to impossible to answer due to not being able to replicate the issue but this still leave some.

A lot of them are genuinely good questions which deserve an answer, so if anyone has any free time to have a quick peek through and attempt to provide a solution, that would be great :)

It will also boost the **Answered Questions** percentage up on Area51

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/unanswered

Comment: What tag did you use for the unanswerable?

Comment: What do you mean which tag did I use for them? I haven't used any tags

Comment: Sorry i read flagged as tagged. Shouldn't be on this right after getting up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to answering unanswered questions, I recommend searching for questions with only one answer (e.g. using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/joomla/query/56690/second-opinion-needed) from the SE Data Explorer), and add additional answers if needed. There might be more than one solution to a problem, and for new visitors it's very useful to see different approaches.

More good answers = higher answer ratio on Area 51.