# Custom Off-Topic Close Reason Approval Process: Too specific or impossible to answer or to replicate

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Considering the discussion on ["Unanswered questions reminder"](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/unanswered-questions-reminder) and some flags on such questions, I am proposing a more clear close reason for questions that cannot be answered:

> **Too specific or impossible to answer or to replicate.** Generally
>   questions about extensions where the software developer is the only
>   one who can offer a solution are off-topic because the community can
>   not provide an answer to the problem.

While not directly mentioned, clearly the time is also a factor. So this close reason should not be used in a first instance, but rather after a decent period of time in which the OP is expected to provide more details or to answer any addressed questions.

**At least one moderator (apart from me) is required to [review](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic) this close reason.**

Any feedback is of course welcome.

Comment: What happens when I click on Close vote button. Do moderators receive any notification? And just an example - http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/6983/contentbuilder-views-component-doesnt-list-views-with-sef-urls. Is this a such type of question?

Comment: When you click Close, your vote will be recorded (not sure about the notification, but I think no). If you need a moderator, just flag the question.

Comment: @DmitryRekun I believe it takes 5 votes to close, unless one of the moderators votes on it, which in that case it closes immediately. There are also certain "auto-flags" that get triggered on some questions that are obviously low quality.

Comment: I like this and it should help with our Area 51 statistics. This should be especially useful where clarification on an unclear question is requested but the OP has not responded within a reasonable time frame.

Answer (score 1):

I might have been a little too trigger happy on the flag button today I'll admit. I don't tend to flag new questions unless they really deserve it. The majority of my flags are when every couple of weeks, I do on a small spree through the Unanswered Questions section and flag those that have not been answered simple due to the fact that they:

1. Cannot be replicated
2. Questions that should be aimed at the developer
3. Have comments that more or less vaguely explain what the issue was but would not really be that suitable to keep on JSE.

Do of course let me know if I've made a mistake with some flags so I know not to make those mistakes again in future :)

Comment: Your point of view is shared by moderators when your flags are marked as useful. Most of the time I share your point of view.